# How to split a string into key-value pairs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have a string such as

```
"@a ipsum lorem @b dolor sit amet @c consectetur adipisicing"
```

That I want to convert to an array (or hash, or some pattern of keys and values)

```
{ @a => "ipsum lorem", @b => "dolor sit amet", @c => "consectetur adipisicing" }
```

Is this possible, and if so how can it be done?

Some important points:

- the keys are a known list of values that are unlikely to conflict
  with other words in the string.
- the keys are designated with a
  symbol `@`
- the keys may be longer than one character e.g. @key,
  @longer-key.
- I'm working in Rails 3.2 with Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Hash[s.scan(/\@\w+/).zip s.split(/\s?\@\w+\s/).drop(1)]
```

Comment: This is a good solution. I've compared performance of this solution (0.000059) and Priti's (0.000097) using `Benchmark.measure`. As this solution is quicker on the string provided, I'm changing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
s = "@a ipsum lorem @b dolor sit amet @c consectetur adipisicing"
Hash[s.split(" ").slice_before(/@/).map{|k,*v|[k,v.join(" ")]}]
#=> {"@a"=>"ipsum lorem", "@b"=>"dolor sit amet", "@c"=>"consectetur adipisicing"}
```

Comment: thanks @priti, this is an elegant solution! A question - if I do not have a symbol @ and instead have a list of values, can these be passed into the `splice_beofore` method? something like `s.chars.splice_before(["a","b","c"])`

Comment: This would have problem if variable name isn't of single character.. e.g. s = "@alpha ipsum lorem @b dolor sit amet @c consectetur adipisicing"

Comment: @Rahulgarg This is all about programming, the thing you are pointing, if that's the scenario can also be handled this way or I may use other technique too. But as per the OP's post I used this technique. And it will for the current example.

Answer (score 1):

```
 s = "@a ipsum lorem @b dolor sit amet @c consectetur adipisicing"
 hs = {}
 s.split('@').drop(1).each{|val| tmp = val.split(' '); hs["@#{tmp.shift}"] = tmp.join(' ')   }
 # puts hs
 #=>{"@a"=>"ipsum lorem", "@b"=>"dolor sit amet", "@c"=>"consectetur adipisicing"}
```

Comment: thanks, this works! One question - if I was not using a symbol @ and instead had a list of values, can these be passed into the `split` method? something like `s.split(["a","b","c"])`

Comment: But then "a" "b" "c" can also be values.. like s = "@a a b @b x y z "

Comment: Above is very specific,assuming your variables are defined @ var_names and rest is the value for it until next @ var is defined;

Comment: @AndyHarvey Is this what you wanted? Then your question is stated wrong.

Comment: @sawa, actually in my case the keys do have @ symbols, my question was more for interest.

Comment: @Rahulgarg, this does answer my question, and is a great solution. I've learned a lot, thanks! I'm going to mark priti as the accepted answer though as it was the first submitted, and achieves the desired result with less code.

Comment: @AndyHarvey I am not mentioning your additional question in the comment. I am mentioning your original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hash[
  string
  .scan(/(@\S+)\s+(.+?)(?=\s+@|\z)/)
  .map{|k, v| [instance_variable_get(k), v]}
]
```

Comment: thanks @sawa can you explain more about this `instance_variable_get` method. I get `NoMethodError: undefined method `instance_varaible_get' for main:Object`

Comment: `instance_variable_get` interprets an instance variable given as a string. For example, if you are in a certain context (`self` is `foo`) on which `@bar` is defined to be `5`, then `foo.instance_variable_get("@bar")` is `5`.

Comment: @Gaurish Sharma Thanks for correcting my typo. That was crucial.

Comment: @AndyHarvey There seems to have been a typo in my answer, which was kindly corrected by Gaurish Sharma. Please try it again.

Comment: thanks @sawa, this looks like a good solution, but I think I must be doing something wrong. I get `=> {nil=>"consectetur adipisicing"}` as the response. What is my mistake?

Comment: @AndyHarvey You have not defined `@c` or have defined it to `nil`.

Comment: @c is defined in the original string, no? `"@a ipsum lorem @b dolor sit amet @c consectetur adipisicing"` I'm looking for a method that will define @c in the output

Comment: You defined instance variables on a string? That is not so commonly seen.

Comment: I have not defined any instance variables, nor do I want to. I have a string that contains certain values and keys. I need to convert this string into a usable format, i.e. keyed array or hash.

Comment: What you have as the keys in your expected result are instance variables. As I wrote in a comment to Rahul garg's answer, you seem to have written the question wrong, and have not fixed it yet.